# How to determine which user invoked the Google Authentication Process

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I want users to allow access to their Google Calender.
For that I request offline access and I want to store the `refresh_token` from Google Auth in database.

Since the client side authentication doesn't allow to get `refresh_token`.

I have a client side script calling the PHP script to invoke the authentication process.

Problem is how do I determine which user has invoked the authentication? so i can save the `refresh_token` for that particular user.

I have tried setting the session in PHP, as `$_SESSION['user_id']` which in my application's `user_id`, but it gets destroyed when redirected from Google and page is reloaded, I only get `$_SESSION['token']` in session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the scopes include openid email, you can request the email using

```
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login?hl=ja#sendauthrequest
```

In your case, it might just be a case of getting your session handling right. Your question didn't contain enough detail to know if this could be the solution.

Comment: Scope is Google Calender Read + Write.

Comment: Yes it was "In your case, it might just be a case of getting your session handling right."

Answer (score 0):

Please add one of the following scopes: email, profile, or openid to the request in order to be able to identify the user.